# How do I get the paintable area in a CFrameWnd with dialog bars?

Tags: user-interface, mfc, coordinates, toolbar

I have a CFrameWnd with a dialog bar, and I'd like to determine the paintable area (excluding the space used by the dialog bar) so I can draw in it without being overlapped by the dialog bar. How can I do this? `GetClientRect()` seems to cover the client rect area as well, and I don't see any other obvious candiates in the doucumentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the [Cwnd::RepositionBars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9y0zwe6(VS.80).aspx) method should provide the information you need. Does the following code work for you?

```
CRect rcClient;
pFrameWnd->RepositionBars(AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_FIRST, AFX_IDW_CONTROLBAR_LAST, 0, CWnd::reposQuery, &rcClient);
```

Comment: That looks like what I might need - can't test until tomorrow though. Is there a window message or callback that I can use to determine when  a toolbar is moved so I can recalculate the client rect then, instead of calling it on every `WM_PAINT`?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with CDockablePane which I solved with

```
CRect rc;
GetDockingManager()->GetClientAreaBounds(rc);
```

but I also ran into the problem of not being able to find a message or callback to know when to trigger it.